# PDFToText not executing from PHP Script

Tags: php, pdftotext

I'm trying to run PDFToText from a PHP script, but I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionaryError: Couldn't open file '/var/www/html/project/pdfdir/estatement.pdf': Permission denied.
Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Error: Couldn't read xref table
Error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Error: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Please note, the permissions are set to 777 on the pdfdir folder and estatement.pdf file.

My PHP script looks like this:

```
$path = '/var/www/html/project/pdfdir/';
$dir = opendir($path);
$filename = array();

while ($filename = readdir($dir)){
  if (!$filename == '.' || '..'){

    $content = shell_exec('/usr/bin/pdftotext '.$path.$filename.' ');        

    $read = strtok ($filename,".");       

    $testfile = $read.".txt";        

    $file = fopen($testfile,"r");

    if (filesize($testfile) == 0){

      echo "file is empty<br><br>";

    }else{

      $text = fread($file,filesize($testfile));
      echo $text;
      fclose($file);

    }
  }
}
```

When I run PDFToText standalone (from /usr/bin/pdftotext) it works with no issues.

Any help appreciated, I'm not sure where to go with this next.

Regards

Comment: Hard to give an answer but it looks like it could be an environment issue. run a script with phpinfo() function and check the $PATH variable. Compare this to your PATH variable for your commandline user. Look for differences that might be relevant to pdftotext. Perhaps a library or other dependency is missing from the PATH. Check for causes of this error with pdftotext - might point to what is amiss.

Comment: Path is set correctly: /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

Comment: Hi @Stephen. Is the fact you are using the full path to the file an issue? My recollection is that pdftotext is pretty portable so try copying pdftotext to your document root or even your project dir and calling it there using a relative path to the file(s). i.e.$path='./pdfdir'; ... shell_exec("./pdftotext ${dir}/${filename}"); ... Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks @ArthurNicoll, I'll try that. I tried a number of different paths but with no luck.

Comment: sorry, just noticed - should have been shell_exec("./pdftotext ${path}/${filename}");